# Haskell digest libraries

Tags: haskell

I need to do some user authentication stuff that involves storing password digest.
I chose sha256 but md5 would do the trick just fine as it is just a learning project and security is not a big deal.

My question is about hundreds of different crypto and hashing libraries and keeping sanity to chose the right one.

I've been through hackage: some libraries fast but not "pure", some "pure but not fast ... and so on with other advantages and disadvantages.

What would you guys use for a sha256 password hashing?

For instance, I found Crypto.Hash.SHA256 and Data.Digest.Pure.SHA.
Which one is more preferable and what is the difference if any?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Data.Digest.Pure.SHA`, from Adam's `SHA` package, is written in only Haskell (hence the 'Pure' in the module name) but is not so fast iirc.  `Crypto.Hash.SHA256` is from Vincent's cipherhash package and is a binding to a fast C implementation.

There is nothing wrong with the C binding from cipherhash - it isn't impure, it doesn't break referential transparency, it's just that I picked a bad module name when building `pureMD5` and that set a precedent.

Comment: Thank you Thomas, I do salt  it before hashing. I just create a random 20 char bytestring then append it to the password and only then hash it.

Comment: That's not enough. HMAC is different from what you're doing. Intentionally slow hashes, like PBKDF2, are best for passwords.

Comment: Yeah, there is a world of difference between a simple hash + salt, and an actual key derivation function.